# Nginx + Node.js + phpmyadmin Настройка

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, phpmyadmin

Доброго времени суток!

Появилась задача опубликовать api написанное на nodejs. На VPS установлен nginx + phpmyadmin(mysql) и нужно добавить node.js.

директории

`nodejs = /var/www/node`

статические файлы nginx (В принципе не нужны так как это api) =

`nginx = var/www/html`

Получается настроить либо работу `node` либо `phpmyadmin`, помогите с файлом конфы nginx, пожалуйста.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default (с рабочим вариантом phpmyadmin)

```cs
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

---

Вопрос был решен удалением phpmyadmin и использование вместо него десктопную версию MySQL Workbench.

И конфиг в связи с этим поменялся на такой (ssl)

```
server {

server_name xxxxxxx.ru www.xxxxxxx.ru;

location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gmelum.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gmelum.ru/privkey.pem; # managed $
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.xxxxxxxx.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = xxxxxxxx.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


listen 80;

server_name xxxxxxx.ru www.xxxxxxx.ru;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настроить можно через прокси в локации, отдельно запускать и мониторить состояние Node сервера через supervisord или альтернативу. Пример конфига для локации [источник](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-run-node-js-server-with-nginx):

```
 location /  {
            proxy_pass    http://localhost:3010;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

Nginx работает либо с CGI(Common Gateway Interface), либо как прокси для статичных ресурсов или неподдерживаемых серверных приложений типа Node.